# Homomorphic image if smaller fails to exist

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

> Suppose a finite group $G$ has no homomorphic image of order $n$. Is it possible for $G$ to have a homomorphic image of order a multiple of $n$?

My gut says "no", as the larger homomorphic image could be made into the smaller by "throwing out" information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** There is no surjective homomorphism from $S_3$ to a group of order $3$ (do you know why?), but there is an obvious surjective homomorphism from $S_3$ to a certain group of order $6$.

Comment: Ah... the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_3$ is $Z_3$ so it can't have an order 3 homomorphic image. And indeed $S_3$ is a homomorphic image of itself. An interesting question might be, is the "other way" true? That is: if $G$ has no homomorphic image of order $n$, then is it impossible for $G$ to have a homomorphic image of order $k$ where $k \mid n$. I believe this is false as well as one can have a group with a no $Z_4$ homomorphic image but a $Z_2$ image.

Comment: Yup, exactly right! For your question about the other direction, an even easier observation would be that every group has a surjective homomorphism to a group of order $1$.